# timestamp for inserting in php

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have this sql query and I need to add a timestamp to a field named 'created' in a previous function that updates. I added `$sqlMod = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET last_modified=now(), %s WHERE id='%s'", $table, $implodeArray, $_POST['id']);` which works just fine. However I cant seem to get that syntax correct in the insert into function for it to work properly. I have tried `(created, %s) VALUES ("now(), %s")`... and it doesnt work.

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ("%s")', $table, implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('",  "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values)));
```

Currently: `INSERT INTO projects (created, project_name, project_bold, project_content, id) VALUES ("now(), something", "something", "something", "46919705")`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_escape_string()`. Use the more comprehensive `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.  In the long run, think about switching to an API supporting prepared statements like MySQLi or PDO, although you still need to concatenate in table names for dynamic SQL such as this.

Comment: `implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values)))`  is wrong.

Comment: INSERT INTO projects (created, project_name, project_bold, project_content, id) VALUES ("now(), something", "something", "something", "46919705")

Comment: @AlixAxel its not wrong u just dont have all the script before it. Believe me it works, except for the created part... unless im mistaken :(

Comment: @Alex: `array_keys($values)` holds the column names, right? If so, they shouldn't be escaped, they should be backticked (`\``) if necessary. Strangely however, they seem to remain intact in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `NOW()` should not be inside quotes, but the arguments that follow it should be quoted.

```
(created, %s) VALUES (now(), "%s")
```

Don't use `mysql_escape_string()`. Use the more comprehensive `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead. In the long run, think about switching to an API supporting prepared statements like MySQLi or PDO, although you still need to concatenate in table names for dynamic SQL such as you are doing.

Although MySQL supports double quotes, single quotes for string values are a little more standard. Swap the quoting on your string and `implode()` call, so the final product looks like:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (created, %s) VALUES (NOW(), '%s')", $table, implode(', ', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode("',  '",array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $values)));
```

As a last point on security for you and for future readers, we don't see the origins of `$table`, but if it originates from any sort of user input, it is advisable to check its value against a whitelist of acceptable table names since it cannot be adequately protected by `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: perfect! thanks man ;) and yea I have to look into sqli. I mean its basically the same thing just the functions have i at the end...? or am i horribly mistaken. i know they have changes security features. and no the table is defined by a previous function btw

Comment: @Alex Constructing a statement like this with a dynamic set of columns and values can be tricky with prepared statements, but they are faster for insert loops, and you needn't worry about escaping input values (but you still need to be careful about table variables)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be putting all the arguments into a single string - that won't work because each argument needs to be a separate entity.

You could probably just use a `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead, and let the database put the creation time in there for you.

Comment: the insert script works fine. im merely trying to add the created field properly. and that wont work with external scripts not in phpMyadmin from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `created` from your `$values` array and hardcoded it in your SQL string.

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s, created) VALUES ("%s", now())', $table, implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('",  "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values)));
```